# Fatal error: Can not redeclare WP_Post_Type show_in_rest

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with a client's Wordpress, I can't fix it.

> Fatal error: Can not redeclare WP_Post_Type :: $ show_in_rest in
>   /home/thesearchhouseco/public_html/buzios/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php
>   on line 348

I have already erased the lines as mentioned, however, it
 still presents an error on another page.

You can see the error at: https://thesearchhouse.com.br/buzios/

File: **class-wp-post-type.php**

> public $show_in_rest;
>
> /**      * The base path for this post type's REST API endpoints.    *
>   * @since 4.7.4     * @access public    * @var string|bool $rest_base   */

Comment: I think we need more context... Starting probably at least 5 lines before the line the error is from, through probably at least 5 lines after. I would also include the line that was there before you deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a class `WP_Post_Type` with a variable `$show_in_rest`. If the class were being accessed by creating a new instance of the class, the variable would likely be editable. From the error, it looks like the variable is being accessed statically (note the `::`), which means it's read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys,

I solved the problem by updating manually the wordpress on my server.

I just downloaded the wordpress, and sent to the server.